# Multiple emails are sent with rewrite rule in place

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in place in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

In the index.php file, I am sending myself an email via the PHP mail function.

```
<?php
$body = "<html>";
$body .= "<body>";
$body .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$body .= "</body>";
$body .= "</html>";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: XXX@domain.com' . "\r\n";

mail('XXX@mail.com', 'IP TEST', $body, $headers, "-fXXX@domain.com");
?>
```

When I access the URL in a web browser http://sub.domain.com, TWO emails are being sent to me.

Same goes for when I access http://sub.domain.com/index.php

When I comment everything out in the .htaccess file, only ONE email is sent.

I don't get it!

Comment: Have you checked the `access.log`?

Comment: `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-"`
`"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 25 "-"`
`"GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-"`
`"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 25 "-"`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in your rule:
from: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico`
needed: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico$`

Also check in firebug in `Network` tab all requested files. It can help to debug.

Comment: I removed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico` all together, and still get two emails.

Comment: why u remove it? u must place correct line. just replace your line (which i wrote in `from`) on My line (given in `needed`). And all will work correctly.

Comment: I replaced the line with the line that you wrote, and it still sends me two emails.

Comment: so check all sended requests. i see u have 2 requests: first on '/', and second on '/index.php'. So just add [R=301,L] for example in your RewriteRule. It prob. helps.

Comment: Those two requests were two separate requests done at two different times.

Answer (score 0):

The favicon request is still going to index.php if that's the default document at your root.  It fails the RewriteCond and falls through to be a standard request.  Try returning 404 for it instead.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```